# get key of dictionary, after the user inputs one element of its list value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

```
{'Juan Pérez': ['Programacion', 'Mecanica', 'Artes'], 'Mauricio Torres': ['Programacion', 'Calculo', 'Literatura']}
```

hey! I have a dictionary and I want to recieve the name of the person after the user inputs one of its elective clases.
for example: the user types "Mecanica", and i recieve "Juan Perez"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
some_dict = {'Juan Pérez': ['Programacion', 'Mecanica', 'Artes'], 'Mauricio Torres': ['Programacion', 'Calculo', 'Literatura']}

user_input = input("Type: ") # catches user's input

result = "" # variable for storing result
for key in some_dict: # iterating through all keys in dictionary
    if user_input in some_dict[key]: # checking if user's input is in value corresponding to key
        result = key
        
print(result)
```